# Using .call() on object method doesn't pass context

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to call a JQuery UI widgets 'custom' method and pass in the `this`/self/context for the purpose of testing. But the context isn't being passed to the method. When I inspect `this` from within the method its `undefined`.

The short example is I call the method using the following code:

```
widget.myWidget('option', "classChangeCallback").call(widget);
```

And when I inspect `this` from inside `classChangeCallback` it is `undefined`. Below is an example of the problem that you can replicate.

```js
(function ($) {

  $.widget( "MY_NAMESPACE.myWidget", {

   options: {

    classChangeCallback: function() {
 
     // When this callback is called via click evt: this.element is defined
     // When this callback is called using .call, .apply: this.element is undefined
     console.log(this.element);
   
   var newEle = $('<div><p>New Element</p></div>')
    .appendTo(this.element)

   return newEle;
  }
 },

 _create: function () {

  this._super( "_create" );

  // Bind to click event as an example only: in my project this 
  // callback is actually called when an elements classes change
  this.element.click(this.options.classChangeCallback.bind(this));
 },

  });

})(jQuery);



// .............

$(document).ready(function() {

 var widget = $('[data-type="foo"]').myWidget();

 // In my testing I want to call the function to test it
 widget.myWidget('option', "classChangeCallback").call(widget);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div data-type="foo" style="min-height:100px; background-color: green;">
  
  <p>
   Bar
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `widget.myWidget('option', "classChangeCallback")` return what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

`$(selector).myWidget()` returns the jQuery object for chaining.

Therefore, in the line `widget.myWidget('option', "classChangeCallback").call(widget);`, you are passing a jQuery object as the context, not a widget instance as the member name suggests.

Although it's rather cumbersome, you could try :

```
widget.myWidget('option', "classChangeCallback").call(widget.myWidget("instance"));
```

But I can't help thinking that you might be better off establishing/triggering a custom event. As it says in the documentation,

> The _on() method provides several benefits of direct event binding:
>
> Maintains proper this context inside the handlers.
>
> ...